# ie problems with jquery - xhr.open(type,s.url,s.async)

Tags: javascript, jquery

one web page all works in FF (and Safari), but IE throws an error on debug on line of jquery
xhr.open(type,s.url,s.async)

Comment: I think you're going to have to add some more details to get a proper answer.

Comment: um, `xhr.open` is not jQuery.

Comment: Is the webpage where you load this code accessible by IP only and doesn't resolve to any host / domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this same problem and it was because the URL I was specifying was empty (I wanted it to target the current URL — this worked fine in Safari). Using `'.'` instead solved the issue for me.